# Where can I find written rulings of the Senate Parliamentarian?

Tags: united-states, senate

Many topics in the news recently refer to rulings made by the Senate Parliamentarian Elizabeth MacDonough. However, so far, I've not been able to find links to the actual text of those rulings.   Does anyone know where I could find an official list of such findings?

Comment: I don't know that they'd be published; a "ruling" could be the Parliamentarian calling the Majority Leader and saying "here's what I think the rules say." Remember that the Parliamentarian is only an advisor; the presiding officer, not the Parliamentarian, actually rules on points of order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According](https://youtu.be/mbR2aZOzJ_g?t=674) to Ryan Grim her opinions are "private", so there won't be an official list... but some do get leaked out (since they apparently circulate among Senators), which is almost certainly how the press ends up quoting from them. (I don't know if there's an unofficial repository somewhere.)